# Pros & Cons of Active Storage compare to CarrierWave & PaperClip

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've just known about ActiveStorage (*It has been a time that I haven't worked with Rails and I've just back to it*). In my previous projects I was more familiar with CarrierWave & PaperClip.

Can somebody explain what're the pros & cons ( or the main reasons ) why people are using this new Rails feature?

Comment: `paperclip` is deprecated now. The main reason people are using are probably ease of use and guaranteed support in future realeases

Answer (score 2):

One reason simply enough is that Paperclip got deprecated https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip, so Active Storage is the official Rails supported solution.

Both provide similar solution/features, so it's a natural transition: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/MIGRATING.md

Answer (score 2):

For me big advantage of ActiveStorage is that I don't need to add file field into each model. Everything is being stored in `active_storage_attachments` table, no additional fields in models where you need uploading.

Also ActiveStorage can resize (and cache resized versions) on the fly. It's very useful when you need to change dimensions of thumbs for records that were already created (see docs for `variant` method).

Answer (score 0):

As with the other Rails components, people would use the build-in solution unless they need some feature which is provided by an external gem only.

Answer (score 0):

Active Storage is not a good fit for a small project where you want to store the uploads to a local disk and serve them from your front-end server. I've spent considerable time trying to cobble something together but it seems AS is only really meant for distributed cloud storage of large volumes of files with complex permissions, where you don't mind hitting the Rails app on every request. I'm going back to [CarrierWave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave), which is still supported and updated to work with Rails 7.1. It also supports `libvips`, which is nice.